# My cat keeps twitching

Tags: cats

i was wondering if anyone can tell me why my cat has been twitching. She doesnt have the symptons of hyperesthesia she just twitches. She is a 12 yr old siamese

Comment: Have you looked at the other questions here about twitching cats? How does your cat's behavior differ from those? What does the vet say?

Comment: This also seems to be a duplicate of "twitching cat wondering why".

Comment: @keshlam if you think it's a duplicate, use the vote to close feature so others look at the resemblance

Comment: Aware of that, @Zaralynda. This touch tablet doesn't always want to cooperate.